# Symfony2 BootstrapBundle: There is no "less" filter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, assetic

I want to use BraincraftedBootstrapBundle on a symfony project.
I followed the steps given on this page: http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started.html

I get the following error:

```
# php app/console assetic:dump
Dumping all dev assets.
Debug mode is on.




  [InvalidArgumentException]  
  There is no "less" filter.  



assetic:dump [--forks="..."] [--watch] [--force] [--period="..."] [write_to]
```

Here is my config.yml file:

```
...
assetic:
    filters:
        less:
            node: /usr/sbin/node
            node_paths: /usr/local/lib/node_modules
            apply_to: "\.less$"
        cssrewrite: ~

braincrafted_bootstrap:
    less_filter: less
```

Comment: Did you install less? `$ npm install -g less`

Comment: Yes less is installed

Comment: Check if you already comment out assetic config in your config_dev.yml.

Answer (score 2):

Look a bit higher up in the `config.yml` you likely already have a `assetic` declaration that came with the installation. You will need to add the new config to that already defined item. (Because your new declaration will be ignored.)

In a standard install you probably have something like

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```

Add the new config to that assetic item, making it:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
        less:
            node: /usr/local/bin/node
            node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules]
            apply_to: "\.less$"
        cssrewrite: ~
```